# How do I fix an "No overload matches this call" of an interface with multiple functions

Tags: typescript, overloading

This is the code I'm struggling with:

```
const enum labelKey {
  RATING = 'asset.ratingPercentage',
  EPISODE_TITLE = 'episode.title.count.short',
  EPISODE_SERIES_TITLE = 'episode.title.series.count.short',
}

interface GetLabel {
  (key: labelKey.RATING, options: { rating: string }): string;
  (
    key: labelKey.EPISODE_TITLE,
    options: { episodeNumber: number; seasonNumber: number; episodeTitle: string },
  ): string;
  (
    key: labelKey.EPISODE_SERIES_TITLE,
    options: { episodeNumber: number; seasonNumber: number; seriesName: string },
  ): string;
  (key: string): string;
}

const getLabel: GetLabel = (key: string, options?: { [key: string]: unknown }) => {
  return '';
};

type Label = {
  key: labelKey.RATING;
  options: { rating: string };
} | {
  key: labelKey.EPISODE_TITLE;
  options: { episodeNumber: number; seasonNumber: number; episodeTitle: string };
} | {
  key: labelKey.EPISODE_SERIES_TITLE;
  options: { episodeNumber: number; seasonNumber: number; seriesName: string };
};

function createLabel(someCondition: boolean): Label {
  if (someCondition) {
    return {
      key: labelKey.RATING,
      options: { rating: '5' },
    };
  }
  else {
    return {
      key: labelKey.EPISODE_TITLE,
      options: { episodeNumber: 1, seasonNumber: 2, episodeTitle: 'Hello'  },
    };
  }
}

const label = createLabel(false);

getLabel(label.key, label.options);
```

I've even added a `labelKey` enum (which I think shouldn't be necessary) to give the hint to TypeScript but `getLabel` still doesn't work.

Any ideas of how this could be accomplished?

Here's the [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=53&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgGwIYCM5oNJwCeMA3gLABQMMASgIIAqAkgHIDiMAvDAOQYQQ4UAHQAnDFACWYAOYAFOKOAIoGGXB4AaStQCicpgGUA8gBFdAfWYMAMrq684AB0kQQAEzjCpUNF9CIYCIQABYgolBaOjD6RmaWhro0TLqGVky29tw8zq4eXj5+woKiknAQwgFBxWERURQAvpSU0lCKAGYYyjBsQjbYuKTRABQA1kQAXOgD+ETC9MzsmjAgTlLgEFMkMOJSslPQpbIwDQCUB1BHMgDcI9HU44RTmDizhMKxJubpmdpU1Cs1pINlt4C43J4WCgcKIpkhkDDrjBBPxwFCEYo4dDFEjchC4AxJL44Bcric-tRzsjLtIbnd-g9JtNXgR3p94hZEslUj87BSAat1pBQXj8uiYViMaIkSi3GBxZiYPDEcjFGUICwMMgSdSyQ1+VTDrTbv8xkyjbJDTTZCamhRKKBILB1FB+q8pr1XTMHGanrractBcDIAB+UEAbUepNpAF0poFRmAQAB3MAnU5cAB8Q3+oiEiFEaZ4PFtJsoUEITjgMDdg245H+UeZuFZ80YrDYJuoQZBpB2Elp0eODVtMAAPjnGX6Xi25uzvtY7F3AULNn3RZDsbClVuZXBUfKt5KVRuCUS-EOZCdRxOG1PnjNW-OEkkUmlF7plz3hevwWKjzuUp7geCrbsqOKqqU5Satql7XpQI7NBQ7SBMAQowMAeYSHAtZoMMbjagAwuA7hEsGUxYCAIB+BgYBUrhk4wJI7QwPhIBESRZHgBmd4AnmUAFmmvEAjATYzm8baLGw-Iid+a7bLsg68AArDw5L3CcMD8BhGxQMudrULggiMdQ-GCSZAJiY+c4GF8lgfjJApAr22ynqBUwAIzLLKaIAQATMsp6EsSUw8AAErgaAgGp6kMpp2mOtA+kIUhiWwOJDiYfubS4cMnRoIIpxlhQLq5eJwiPMs5VyUVlBAA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of the problem is that you don't know the type of `label.key` at the point when you call `getLabel`.  So none of the first three overloads can be matched as those all require specific key types.  But you can't match the fourth `string` overload either because this overload `(key: string): string;` requires that you don't pass a second argument.

#### Solution 1: `getLabel`

Let's add an overload where we know we have a `labelKey` but don't know which one.  So we should accept the `options` for any of the overloads without requiring that the options type matches the key type.  Then as a last resort you can add another overload that accepts any `string` and any `options` object.

```
interface GetLabel {
...exisiting overloads 1-3...
  (key: Label['key'], options: Label['options']): string;
  (key: string, options: Record<string, any>): string;
}
```

#### Solution 2: `createLabel`

But we can also tackle the issue from the `createLabel` function.  Currently Typescript does not know which type of `Label` this function returns.  But we should be able to know which `Label` we will get based on the value of `someCondition` that we call the function with.  So we can actually add overloads here.  Note: you don't actually need `as const` when you have an explicit return type.

```
// helper function to get a member of the `Label` union
type LabelByKey<K extends labelKey> = Extract<Label, {key: K}>

function createLabel(someCondition: true): LabelByKey<labelKey.RATING>;
function createLabel(someCondition: false): LabelByKey<labelKey.EPISODE_TITLE>;
function createLabel(someCondition: boolean): Label {
  if (someCondition) {
    return {
      key: labelKey.RATING,
      options: { rating: '5' },
    }
  }
  else {
    return {
      key: labelKey.EPISODE_TITLE,
      options: { episodeNumber: 1, seasonNumber: 2, episodeTitle: 'Hello'  },
    }
  }
}
```

Now when you call `createLabel(false)` you know that you get a label whose type looks like:

```
const label: {
    key: labelKey.EPISODE_TITLE;
    options: {
        episodeNumber: number;
        seasonNumber: number;
        episodeTitle: string;
    };
}
```

We don't need those extra overloads because now we are able to match the second overload with `key: labelKey.EPISODE_TITLE`.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/w8vLrm)

#### Solution 3: Generics

The information that you need to match a `labelKey` with its `options` is already available in the `Label` union.  So you don't need to type it out again in the overloads.  We can use a generic function instead of an overloaded one and make use of the same `LabelByKey` helper type.

```
type LabelByKey<K extends labelKey> = Extract<Label, {key: K}>

const getLabel = <K extends labelKey>(
  key: K,
  options: LabelByKey<K>['options']
) => {
  return '';
};
```

Comment: So the trick is to not use an overloaded function but instead use a `Label` union and then some TS magic to extract the appropriate label from that union. Thanks Linda! This is a pretty comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 2):

if you change the definition of `label` to

```
const label = {
  key: labelKey.RATING,
  options: { rating: '5' },
} as const;
```

the inferred type of the `key` property will be `labelKey.RATING` instead of `labelKey` and you won't get this error

Here's the [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgGwIYCM5oNJwCeMA3gLABQMMASgIIAqAkgHIDiMAvDAOQYQQ4UAHQAnDFACWYAOYAFOKOAIoGGXB4AaStQCicpgGUA8gBFdAfWYMAMrq684AB0kQQAEzjCpUNF9CIYCIQABYgolBaOjD6RmaWhro0TLqGVky29tw8zq4eXj5+woKiknAQwgFBxWERURQAvpSU0lCKAGYYyjBsQjbYuKTRABQA1kQAXOgD+ETC9MzsmjAgTlLgEFMkMOJSslPQpbIwDQCUB1BHMgDcI9HU44RTmDizhMKxJubpmdpU1Cs1pINlt4C43J4WCgcKIpkhkDDrjBBPxwFCEYo4dDFEjchC4AxJL44Bcric-tRzsjLtIbnd-g9JtNXgR3p94hZEslUj87BSAat1pBQXj8uiYViMaIkSi3GBxZiYPDEcjFGUICwMMgSdSyQ1+VTDrTbv8xkyjbJDTTZCamhRKKBILB1FB+q8pr1XTMHGanrractBcDIAB+UEAbUepNpAF0poFRmAQAB3MAnU5cAB8Q3+oiEiFEaZ4PFtJsoUEITjgMDdg245H+UeZuFZ80YrDYJuoQZBpB2Elp0eODVtMAAPjnGX6Xi25uzvtY7F3AULNn3RZDsbClVuZXBUfKt5KVRuCUS-EOZCdRxOG1PnjNW-OEkkUmlF7plz3hevwWKjzuUp7geCrbsqOKqqU5Satql7XpQI7NBQjrQM2aAOHeMBNjObxtosbD8t+a7bLsg68AArDw5IITA-AwChUBlhQLq1mgww4cIjzLBxRGnCaQA)

--

**Edit:** you can replace your overloads using generics based on the definition of the `Label`

```
interface GetLabel {
  <K extends labelKey>(key: K, options: Extract<Label, {key: K}>['options']): string;
  (key: string): string;
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#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-1Pgw9YOX+RFgRgABGP0BRhATRgAJj9Pi0QxPxcIACVwNAQEIhoOLIplyPIygK2gR0em4fdDy1E9dTQQQMw3ChqxPWC0GES4-Qc4R0OsoA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Teneff! Unfortunately my example wasn't realistic enough, I was missing a function. I've updated my question now. Adding `const` to each branch of that function doesn't seem to work. Do you see a way out of this?

Comment: @Ashitaka I've updated my answer and I've noticed that it pretty much overlaps with the one below